# Allow only branch creator to delete Github branch

Tags: github, branch

I have branch protection rule in place in Github which matches all branches so none can be deleted. I want to change that to a case where the person who created the branch should be able to delete it. So, I can delete my branch but not of someone else's and vice versa

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to add security on individual things in most things GitHub. In general, there is a revert option for these actions, since the commits these branches pointed to will never really go away anyway.

You can add a Branch Protection to a branch to prevent accidental deletions, but you can't auto-restrict the allow deletions of those branches to the person who originally pushed that branch:

[image]